# Android application that starts another application when phone is not in use since 1 minute

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application which runs another android application when the phone or tablet  pc is not in use for one minute. In other words, this application should listen to the device. If there is no action in use for one minute, another choosen android application should be run.
Thanx!

Comment: Do you want this behavior during only one application, or when every application runs on the device?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. Your application can't really tell what is or isn't running. This sounds like malicious code. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Everything can be done on android but this behaviour would drain tons of energy to implement. Figure something else out for you and your users...

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is something like a input monitor to record key strokes. On every key stroke, start a timer of 1 minute. If there is no response, start your code.

I have worked earlier on symbian platform, there we do have such monitors. So there is a possibility that it might work on android too.

Comment: You cannot intercept the IME to monitor key strokes on Android unless you have programmed one on you own. The trick would be to run a background service that checks for new processes. But still it depends on your definition of 'No action in use' as mentioned by the asker.